# Jest spy on a function inside a custom hook

Tags: jestjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook called `useCustom`, that implements a function called `doSomething`.
In my react component I want to spy on the `doSomething` that it has been called with certain values. But it never gets called. What would be the proper way to mock or spy on that `doSomething` method?

This is what I tried:

myComponent.tsx

```
...
const { doSomething} = useCustom();
doSomething('a','b');
...
```

useCustom.ts

```
export const useCustom= () => {
  const doSomething = (param1, param2): void => {
    ...
  };

  return { doSomething };
```

myComponent.spec.ts

```
it('should call dosomething', () => {
    const doSomethingSpy= jest.spyOn(useCustom(), 'doSomething');
    ...
    expect(doSomethingSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('a','b');
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I now managed to do it like this:

```
import * as useCustomHook from '@hooks/useCustom';

it('should call doSomething', () => {
    const doSomethingMock= jest.fn();
    jest.spyOn(useCustomHook, 'useCustom').mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
         doSomething: doSomethingMock,
      };
     });
     ...
     expect(doSomethingMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('a','b');
 });
```