# How to mock corectly custom hook or spy on methods of a mocked module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, mocking

After two days of trials and errors I finally ran out of ideas for what to do.

I tried to search for similar questions on SO and I found only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68650474/jest-spy-on-a-function-inside-a-custom-hook). It is similar to my problem, but I was unable to figure out any working solutions based on it.

I am trying to test a simple component, and I have a problem with how to mock `useToggleModal()` hook. I tried two ways to do so, and both failed.

first relevant files:

**component** under test

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { IconMenu } from '@common/components';
import { MODALS } from '@utils/consts';
import useToggleModal from '@hooks/useToggleModal';
import { getHistoryDetails } from '@redux/historyDetails/actions';

export const TableIconMenu = ({data, handleDetails}) => {
  const { showErrorModal, showModal } = useToggleModal();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleHistoryPromise = id => {
    return dispatch(getHistoryDetails(id));
  };

  const showModalData = async (id, dataHandler, modalName) => {
    showModal(MODALS.INFO, { infoMessage: { isLoading: true } });

    const result = await dataHandler(id);

    if (result.error) {
      showErrorModal(result.error?.message);
    } else {
      showModal(modalName, { details: result.payload?.data });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <IconMenu.Item
        onClick={() =>
          showModalData(
            data.id,
            handleHistoryPromise,
            MODALS.HISTORY
          )
        }
      >
        History
      </IconMenu.Item>
      <IconMenu.Item
        onClick={() => handleDetails(data.id)}
      >
        Refresh details
      </IconMenu.Item>
      <IconMenu.Item
        onClick={() => showModalData(
            data.id,
            handleDetails,
            MODALS.EDIT
          )
        }
      >
        Edit
      </IconMenu.Item>
    </>
  );
};
export default TableIconMenu;
```

and `useToggleModal` hook

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { INFO_MODAL_TYPES, MODALS } from '@utils/consts';
import { closeModal, openModal } from '@redux/common/modals/actions';

const useToggleModal = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); //source of troubles in Attempt 1

  const showModal = (modal, data) => {
    dispatch(openModal({ data, modal }));
  };

  const hideModal = () => {
    dispatch(closeModal());
  };

  const showErrorModal = message =>
    showModal(MODALS.INFO, {
      infoMessage: {
        errorMessage: message,
        errors: true,
        loading: false,
        type: INFO_MODAL_TYPES.ERROR
      }
    });

  const showSuccessModal = message =>
    showModal(MODALS.INFO, {
      infoMessage: {
        isLoading: false,
        message,
        type: INFO_MODAL_TYPES.SUCCESS
      }
    });

  return {
    hideModal,
    showErrorModal,
    showModal,
    showSuccessModal
  };
};

export default useToggleModal;
```

## Attempt 1

Initially I tried to import `useToggleModal` module in this way `import * as useToggleModal from '@hooks/useToggleModal';` and then set a spy on `showModal` method. But this doesn't work because `useToggleModal` internally is using `dispatch` from `react-redux` and this gives me error

> "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:..."

On the other hand importing `import * as ReactRedux from 'react-redux';` and mocking `useDispatch`method `jest.spyOn(ReactRedux, 'useDispatch').mockReturnValue(jest.fn());` collides with `configureStore` and breaks `expect(dispatchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(details);` assertion.

whole test looks like this - ***approach 1***

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import * as useToggleModal from '@hooks/useToggleModal';
import * as actions from '@redux/historyDetails/actions';
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import TableIconMenu from './TableIconMenu';

describe('TableIconMenu', () => {
  let mockStore;
  let store;
  let data;
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockStore = configureStore();

    data = {
      id: 123
    };
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('should be able to click button', () => {
    store = mockStore({});
    const details = { test: 'test' };

    const spyShowModal = jest.spyOn(useToggleModal.default(), 'showModal');
    const handleHistorySpy = jest.spyOn(actions, 'getHistoryDetails').mockReturnValue(details);
    const dispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({ payload: { data: 'hello there' } }));

    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <TableIconMenu data={data} handleDetails={jest.fn()} />
      </Provider>
    );

    const button = screen.getByText('History');
    expect(button).toBeTruthy();
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(handleHistorySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(dispatchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(details);
    expect(spyShowModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

## Attempt 2

Then I tried to mock whole `useToggleModal` module as shown below, but I don't know how to spy on `showModal` method. I see that `console.log('show modal args: ', args);` prints correct `args` object (twice as I expected) but despite of this `expect(spyShowModal).toHaveBeenCalled()` shows 0 calls.

whole test looks like this (almost the same as first one except `jest.mock`) - ***approach 2***

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import * as useToggleModal from '@hooks/useToggleModal';
import * as actions from '@redux/historyDetails/actions';
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import TableIconMenu from './TableIconMenu';

jest.mock('@hooks/useToggleModal', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => ({
    showErrorModal: jest.fn(),
    showModal: (...args) => {
      console.log('show modal args: ', args);
      return jest.fn();
    }
  })
}));

describe('TableIconMenu', () => {
  let mockStore;
  let store;
  let data;
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockStore = configureStore();

    data = {
      id: 123
    };
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('should be able to click button', () => {
    store = mockStore({});
    const details = { test: 'test' };

    const spyShowModal = jest.spyOn(useToggleModal.default(), 'showModal');
    const handleHistorySpy = jest.spyOn(actions, 'getHistoryDetails').mockReturnValue(details);
    const dispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({ payload: { data: 'hello there' } }));

    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <TableIconMenu data={data} handleDetails={jest.fn()} />
      </Provider>
    );

    const button = screen.getByText('History');
    expect(button).toBeTruthy();
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(handleHistorySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(dispatchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(details);
    expect(spyShowModal).toHaveBeenCalled(); //not working, spyShowModal have not been called
  });
});
```

**My questions are (not sure which is correct/better):**

1. How to correctly mock useToggleModal without error message "Invalid hook call..." as in **Attempt 1** or
2. How to spy on methods when whole module is mocked as in **Attempt 2**?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

In your approach2, Since you are expecting the mock method to be called , you can use the below syntax to check calls for mocked method.

```
expect(spyShowModal.mock.calls).toHaveLength(2)
```

and I believe the expect call that you have written is checking the original method to be called. since you have mocked that module, It wont get called thus the testcase failing

we can expect mock args or mock results or mock result for each mock calls using the above mentioned syntax. Please check this documentation https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions.

Solution 2:

Can you try giving reference like this

```
    const showModalfn = jest.fn()

    jest.mock('@hooks/useToggleModal', () => ({
          __esModule: true,
          default: () => ({
            showErrorModal: jest.fn(),
            showModal: showModalfn
          })
        }))
    
    expect(showModalfn).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: @crotylaldehyde please let me know if this solution works. else we can check the spyOn statement for getting the mock reference.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working `mock.calls` has length 0.

Comment: @crotylaldehyde Could you please try the solution 2 and let me know if it works

Comment: This proposition 2 won't work either because, as far as I know `jest.mock` is hoisted at the beginning of the file and `showModalfn` will be undefined.
I tried to use `jest.doMock` but after this I got back to case 1 and "Invalid hook call. `Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component... ` errror.

Comment: @crotylaldehyde I was mentioning about adding that showModalfn as a global variable only on the top of the file before jest.mock. It may work but not sure though